# Save Stripe customer id after checkoiut in my database with Mongoose

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose, stripe-payments

I set up Stripe Checkout with Customer Portal and I want to be able to retrieve the customer id to let the user go to his portal.
In order:

1. I want to retrieve the customer id
2. Save it in my DB (The user is already logged in).

The checkout form works well, the redirection too. But I'm unable to retrieve the customer id (nothing appears when I `console.log()` it.

My Express code:

```
  router.post("/create-checkout-session", ensureAuthenticated, async (req, res) => {
    const { priceId } = req.body;
    try {
      const session = await stripe.checkout.sessions.create({
        mode: "subscription",
        payment_method_types: ["card"],
        line_items: [
          {
            price: priceId,
            quantity: 1,
          },
        ],
        
        success_url: 'http://localhost:3000/fr/premiereconnexion?session_id={CHECKOUT_SESSION_ID}'
      });
    
      res.send({
        sessionId: session.id,
      });
    }
    catch (e) {
    res.status(400);
    return res.send({
      error: {
        message: e.message,
      }
    });
  }
});

router.post('/premiereconnexion', ensureAuthenticated, async (req, res) => {
  const session = await stripe.checkout.sessions.retrieve(req.query.session_id);
  const customerId = await stripe.customers.retrieve(session.customer.id);
  console.log(customerId);
  
  req.user.stripeCustomer = customerId
  req.user.save()
});
router.get('/premiereconnexion', ensureAuthenticated, (req, res) => {
  res.render('users/fr/endpayment', {
    user: req.user
  })
})
```

My User model:

```
const User = new Schema({
    firstName: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    lastName: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    email: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        unique: true,
        required: true
    },
    stripeCustomer: {
        type: String,
        default: null
    }
});
```

The first problem is to be able to call the customer ID. I don't even know how I can do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
const customerId = await stripe.customers.retrieve(session.customer.id)
```

Customer on the Session object [is just an ID](https://stripe.com/docs/api/checkout/sessions/object#checkout_session_object-customer) — it's the ID itself. You can [expand](https://stripe.com/docs/expand) it but you don't seem to. It's not an object that has an `id` field. So customer.id is null.

Try doing just `customerId = session.customer` instead.

Note also you shouldn't really be doing this logic on the page that is the `success_url`. The customer might not visit that since they might close the browser straight after paying. You should use webhooks. https://stripe.com/docs/payments/checkout/fulfill-orders

Comment: I modified it and the console.log() doesn't print anything

Comment: I know this is an old question but it's referenced in other stripe posts, but I get `session is not defined` when I try to log @karllekko. @If_celine were you able to find an answer?