# Retrieve customer ID in stripe during checkout

Tags: express, stripe-payments

I have a Stripe checkout and I want to retrieve the customer ID if it'a success. I followed the Stripe tutorial but it doesn't work for me (The checkout works well but I can't retrieve the customer ID to add it to my User database)

My code:

```
router.post("/create-checkout-session", ensureAuthenticated, async (req, res) => {
    const { priceId } = req.body;

    // See https://stripe.com/docs/api/checkout/sessions/create
    // for additional parameters to pass.
    try {
      const session = await stripe.checkout.sessions.create({
        mode: "subscription",
        payment_method_types: ["card"],
        line_items: [
          {
            price: priceId,
            // For metered billing, do not pass quantity
            quantity: 1,
          },
        ],
        // {CHECKOUT_SESSION_ID} is a string literal; do not change it!
        // the actual Session ID is returned in the query parameter when your customer
        // is redirected to the success page.
        success_url: 'http://localhost:3000/fr/premiereconnexion?session_id={CHECKOUT_SESSION_ID}',
        cancel_url: 'https://localhost:3000/fr/erreursouscription',
      });
    
      res.send({
        sessionId: session.id,
        customerID: session.customer
      });
    }
    catch (e) {
    res.status(400);
    return res.send({
      error: {
        message: e.message,
      }
    });
  }
  }
});
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Save Stripe customer id after checkoiut in my database with Mongoose](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66543970/save-stripe-customer-id-after-checkoiut-in-my-database-with-mongoose)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How are you retrieving the Customer ID?

You should process the `success_url` by extracting the query params and retrieving `session_id` through an API call to Stripe to obtain the `customer`: https://stripe.com/docs/api/checkout/sessions/retrieve. So you should have a `get(...)` route for the `success_url` route.

Alternatively, listen to the `checkout.session.completed` webhook event.

Comment: Just a note, because I ran into this. By default `checkout.session.completed` will only have a customer ID if the session was related to buying a subscription.

Comment: Can I add a customer id in `stripe.checkout.sessions.create()`? I'm worrying about if the user disconnect after making a payment and before redirecting to `success_url` so that I would lost the customer information?