# Retrieve customer ID from stripe checkout

Tags: stripe-payments, checkout

This is a bit related to [Retrieve customer ID in stripe during checkout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66549420/retrieve-customer-id-in-stripe-during-checkout). However, I'm trying to move to the [stripe-hosted](https://checkout.stripe.dev/) version of Stripe Checkout.

The problem is there is no efficient way of linking a payment to a customer. We could search for a customer via email on successful payment, however this assumes they've entered the same email in the checkout screen as the one they used to sign into our app.

Here's the checkout screen:[image]

Here's where you would set a callback url in stripe's pricing wizard:
[image]

I've asked Stripe about this and there are no solutions currently. I've requested simply passing back the customer id in the callback which might solve it. Has anyone found a sufficient work around?

Comment: What are you trying to do exactly? It's not clear what isn't working like you expect/need. If a Checkout session is created with a supplied customer or ends up creating one itself, that `customer` ID will be on the session object after it is completed. It looks like you might be using payment links, which do not currently support specifying existing customer IDs.

Comment: Could you also clarify what you mean by trying to move to self-hosted checkout? Are you moving from Checkout to your own custom payment flow?

Comment: The self-hosted checkout doesn't use a checkout session which makes the session flow obsolete. What I'm trying to do is simply move a user to the role/plan they paid for. A customer pays using stripe, now I need to convert them to a customer in our app.

Comment: I'm still not clear what you mean by self-hosted Checkout. Do you mean a custom payment flow you build using Elements? If so, you control (optional) customer creation in that case, and can do so whenever you deem appropriate in your flow.

Comment: Everything you've shown & linked to refers to Stripe-hosted Checkout. Perhaps you can revise your question with details of your own code & integration to clarify where you're having trouble.

Comment: stripe-hosted*** this was a typo

Comment: @tqrecords Did you find a solution? I'm looking to accomplish the same.

Comment: @Kev Right now I'm retrieving their account details by the email they entered in the stripe checkout. I've found that I have to add a delay (10 seconds), to ensure the email is propagated in stripe. That's the only way I can link them right now. It's clunky, because it assumes they enter the same email they signed up with. I followed up with stripe again to see if they have a solution.